# How to avoid to send the mail to owner field

Tags: apex, send-email

I have used the following code for sending the mail with template. but I don't want to send the mail to owner.

```
 List<String> toAddress = new List<String>();
        toAddress.add(my email address);
        email.setTemplateId(tmpl.Id);
        email.setToAddresses(toAddress);
        email.setTargetObjectId(userid);
        email.setWhatId(oppId);
```

If we set `setTargetObjectId`, the mail send to owner. So, how to avoid to send the mail to owner that?

Answer (score 2):

@Lemon, You want to follow the code example found here:

[Using APEX to assemble HTML Letterhead Emails](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/13/using-apex-to-assemble-html-letterhead-emails/8745#8745)

Essentially, by wrapping the sendEmail call in a db transaction that you immediately rollback, you end up with a Merged template that you can inject into a send without using setTargetObjectId.

I've taken the liberty of writing up this as a class, as part of my upcoming "highly opinionated standard library."

```
public class mailUtils {
  public class mailUtilsException extends exception {}

  public Boolean useSig {get; private set;}
  public Boolean saveActivity {get; private set;}
  public String senderDisplayName {get; private set;}

  public mailUtils(Boolean useSig, Boolean saveActivity, String senderDisplayName){
    this.useSig = usesig;
    this.saveActivity = saveActivity;
    this.senderDisplayName = senderDisplayName;
  }

  // Derived from: 
  // https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/13/using-apex-to-assemble-html-letterhead-emails/8745#8745
  public Messaging.SingleEmailMessage MergeTemplateWithoutSending(Id targetObjectId, Id templateId) {
    Messaging.reserveSingleEmailCapacity(1);
    Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
    // Intentionally set a bogus email address.
    String[] toAddresses = new String[]{'invalid@emailaddr.es'};
    mail.setToAddresses(toAddresses);
    mail.setUseSignature(this.useSig);
    mail.setSaveAsActivity(this.saveActivity);
    mail.setSenderDisplayName(this.senderDisplayName);
    mail.setTargetObjectId(targetObjectId);
    mail.setTemplateId(templateId);

    // create a save point
    Savepoint sp = Database.setSavepoint();
    // Force the merge of the template.
    Messaging.sendEmail(new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[] {mail});
    // Force a rollback, and cancel mail send.
    Database.rollback(sp);

    // Return the mail object
    // You can access the merged template, subject, etc. via:
    // String mailTextBody = mail.getPlainTextBody();
    // String mailHtmlBody = mail.getHTMLBody();
    // String mailSubject = mail.getSubject();
    return mail;

  }

  public static Map<String,String> getMergedTemplateForObjectWithoutSending(Id targetObjectId, Id templateId, Boolean useSig, Boolean saveActivity, String senderDisplayName) {
    Map<String,String> returnValue = new Map<String,String>();
    mailUtils mu = new mailUtils(useSig, saveActivity, senderDisplayName);
    Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mail = mu.MergeTemplateWithoutSending(targetObjectId, templateId);
    returnValue.put('textBody', mail.getPlainTextBody());
    returnValue.put('htmlBody', mail.getHTMLBody());
    returnValue.put('subject', mail.getSubject());
    return returnValue;
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you mean by default email code.. but my guess is you can use the  **setToAddresses** method to specify the email address to whom you want to send

https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_classes_email_outbound_single.htm#apex_Messaging_SingleEmailMessage_setToAddresses

This is just a sample code for reference

```
        EmailTemplate tmpl = [SELECT Id, Subject, HtmlValue, Body FROM EmailTemplate WHERE DeveloperName = 'YourTemplateName' limit 1];
        Messaging.SingleEmailMessage email = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();        
        email.setOrgWideEmailAddressId(YourFromAddr.Id);
        List<String> toAddress = new List<String>();
        toAddress.add(YourToEmail);
        email.setTemplateId(tmpl.Id);
        email.setToAddresses(toAddress);
        email.setTargetObjectId(contactId);
        email.setWhatId(oppId);
        Messaging.sendEmail(new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[] { email });
```

Comment: Thanks. But if we set the targetobject id, the mail sent to owner. so i want to prevent. can you help?

Answer (score 0):

As per documentation:

[setTargetObjectId(ID](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_classes_email_outbound_single.htm)) 
Required if using a template, optional otherwise. The ID of the contact, lead, or user to which the email will be sent. The ID you specify sets the context and ensures that merge fields in the template contain the correct data.

This seems like its designed to work like that.

If you want to send email other email id then you will not be able to use template.

One work around is define HTML email body instead of template and then use setToAddresses

Comment: If we put the settargetobjectid, user will get the mail but I dont want to send that mail how to protect that?

Comment: Have you read and understood my answer? settargetobjectid designed for that and you cant prevent that that. you will need to write your own code as said above.

Comment: Yes. but I need to prevent that so is there any hack for that?